# Promise returning unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have the following:

```
     return indexedDbClient.getStorageUsedInGb().then(function (storageUsedInGb) {
         var evictedMediaGuids = [];
         storageUsedInGb = parseFloat(storageUsedInGb);
         if (storageUsedInGb > storageQuotaInGb) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                const store = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite").objectStore(storeName);
                (function loop(storageUsedInGb) {
                    if (storageUsedInGb <= storageQuotaInGb) {
                        resolve({
                            evictedMediaGuids: evictedMediaGuids,
                            shouldStopStoring: false
                        });
                    } else {
                        const latestMediaRequest = store.getAll();
                        latestMediaRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
                            const allData = event.target.result;
                            const targetEntry = allData[0];
                            const deleteRequest = store.delete(targetEntry.media.guid);
                            evictedMediaGuids.push(targetEntry.media.guid);
                            deleteRequest.onsuccess = loop.bind(null, storageUsedInGb - event.target.media.size / 1024 / 1000 / 1000);
                            deleteRequest.onerror = reject;
                         }
                         latestMediaRequest.onerror = reject;
                    }
               })(storageUsedInGb); // call immediately
            }) 
         } else {
             return Promise.resolve({
                 evictedMediaGuids: evictedMediaGuids,
                 shouldStopStoring: false
             });
         }
        }).then(function (storeObject) {
            // do stuff to object
            return Promise.resolve(storeObject)
        });
```

The idea is that `loop(storageUsedInGb)` forces the resolution to wait for the `return`; however `handleStoreObject` gets invoked immediately after `loop` - with no sign of the `latestMediaRequest` `onsuccess` handler being invoked.  What am I doing wrong?

I am using bluebird in case it matters.

Comment: your first `.then` doesn't (always) return anything (when (storageUsedInGb > storageQuotaInGb) is true), therefore anything asynchronous inside that block of code is not waited for... also, your second `.then` never returns anything either, so the end result (once you fix the problem) will be a promise that resolves to `undefined` - is that what you expect?

Comment: @JaromandaX - I just added the "resolve" in the last `then` - the first `then` should always return - through the loop.  Should I return an inner `Promise` from outside the loop that calls some kind of `innerResolve` on the `<=` instead of returning the object directly?

Comment: You have an extra `}` just before the `else`.

Comment: Now you've added a Promise constructor anti pattern

Comment: when `if (storageUsedInGb > storageQuotaInGb) {` you still don't handle any asynchronous code in there, and you still don't return anything anyway

Comment: see this comment `// call immediately` ... really that comment should say `// call immediately and ignore any return value`

Comment: There's no need for `new Promise` at all. `indexedDbClient.getStorageUsedInGb()` already is one

Comment: @JaromandaX - in that case, the intent is to loop until it returns, and then call `resolve` on the returned object.  I admit I am just learning promises :)

Comment: the issue is, the functions in that loop do not return promises, so they will have to be promisified (wrapped in new Promise) - whereas, the entire code should **not** be wrapped in a new Promise, seeing as `indexedDbClient.getStorageUsedInGb()` returns a promise already - you only need to promisify asynchronous code that doesn't return a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX - I see.  How would I go about resolving/rejecting without the `resolve` / `reject` callbacks?  Just return an object or throw an Error, respectively?

Comment: no, any asynchronous code inside a .then that does not understand promises needs to be "wrapped" in a promise constructor, (or, as you are using bluebird, promisified)

Comment: @JaromandaX just tried an updated approach (edited code above) - however now I'm getting the last `then` called on the *second* iteration of the loop.

Comment: because a promise can only be resolved once

Comment: @JaromandaX - it never calls `resolve` before hitting the final `then`... thanks for your patience by the way

Comment: Looking at the re-written code, I can't see why it wouldn't work as expected - the `new Promise` will clearly only resolve once `storageUsedInGb <= storageQuotaInGb` - as a side note: you don't need either of the `return Promise.resolve(` - they can just be `return` as anything you return in a `.then` is already going to be a promise anyway

Comment: Your question mentions that `handleStoreObject` gets executed too soon, but I don't see that call anywhere in your code.